# Proxifying ASP.NET page in PHP causes AJAX error

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, proxy

I'm working on building a PHP based proxy script to access a particular ASP.NET page that uses lots of AJAX.  So far most of the website works, but one of the forms produces the following error upon submittal:

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.`

`Details: Error parsing near '
<!DOCTYPE html P'.`

I've checked the headers that my proxy script sends/receives, and they're identical to what would actually be sent my a web browser like FF.  I've checked the page source to make sure everything that should be in tact is so.  I've also verified there aren't any javascript errors on the page.

Can anyone suggest an approach to continue troubleshooting the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you miss an AJAX call in your proxy, there could be some cross domain errors. Also, make sure you are not accidentally stripping any non-standard headers like X-MicrosoftAjax.

Comment: I added the header `X-MicrosoftAjax` and am receiving a different and more descriptive problem.  Thank you very much for the tip.